# Making Private Domain Marriage Public Domain Name - Revisited

Tags: domain-name-system, security, domain, windows-server-2012

I'm building a server with Windows Server 2012 and I've checked many articles on the net about "naming" your internal domain. Interestingly, most of the comments are from 2009. As we all know, times have changed, security and hacking strategies have changed, and of course with Windows server 2012, there is new changes.

I've always been a guy who fell into the old .local scheme of things, but recently have started using my public domain name and just adding "ad.pubdomian.com" or "corp.pubdomain.com" to create the internal domain. Although an IT professional, most of my skill set as a business owner lies in the copier/printer/scanner business and only interfaces with IT infrastructures.

Pride and ignorance are the only two things which stops a man from asking ANY question that he doesn't have 100% assurance of. With that said, I'd love to get some feedback on this subject matter with IT professionals who actually deal with creating new Network infrastructures all the time.

One reason I have a "concern" with naming my internal domain, is that I am encompassing two offices into one. Normally that isn't a big deal, except in this case, the first location is in the United States and the other location is the Philippines and I'm being overly cautious on purpose... :)

How does the "international" adjoining of two offices into one change the way I should think about my naming strategies? Are there "other" security considerations I should consider besides the "basics" in Infrastructure security and domain naming?

Thanks in advance for any helpful information you provide........

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "naming" and "security" have in common in your question. They are separate things.

*For naming*: Don't use .local or other non-TLD's. Microsoft does not recommend it, and we start seeing new TLD's on a regular basis now. While .local has been specifically banned from being registered as a TLD, it is still very recommended to get your own public name and use this as a base for your AD naming scheme.

This means, your choices of ad.pubdomain.com or corp.pubdomain.com are valid and good.

*As for "security"*, it all depends on your needs.
You can have two separate forests, both living in ad.pubdomain.com (us.ad.pubdomain.com / philippines.ad.pubdomain.com), so they are completely separate in terms of security.

If you expect for the businesses to be "divorced" again, then you might want to have two public domains   ad.pubdomain.us and ad.pubdomain.ph.

You can also integrate them in one Domain, or into multiple domains in the same forest.

It all very much depends on your requirements and needs way more info from your side.

Comment: Another reason not to use .local: OS X (and anything else that uses multicast DNS per [RFC6762](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6762)) will resolve names ending in .local via mDNS instead of normal DNS. Recent versions of OS X have hacky workarounds that'll let them mostly work in .local AD domains... but only mostly. And OS X is getting more popular in corporate environments...